# pandas dataframe to existing excel worksheet and wrap column text with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm writing a dataframe to existing excel worksheet. I need to preserve the worksheet formatting. I can do this with openpyxl however I can't figure out how to wrap the text in the column. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame() 
df['id'] = [1,2]
df['reviews'] = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna felis sollicitudin mauris. Integer in mauris eu nibh euismod gravida. Duis ac tellus et risus vulputate vehicula. Donec lobortis risus a elit. Etiam tempor. Ut ullamcorper, ligula eu tempor congue, eros est euismod turpis, id tincidunt sapien risus a quam. Maecenas fermentum consequat mi. Donec fermentum. Pellentesque', 'malesuada nulla a mi. Duis sapien sem, aliquet nec, commodo eget, consequat quis, neque. Aliquam faucibus, elit ut dictum aliquet, felis nisl adipiscing sapien, sed malesuada diam lacus eget erat. Cras mollis scelerisque nunc. Nullam arcu. Aliquam consequat. Curabitur augue lorem, dapibus quis, laoreet et, pretium ac, nisi. Aenean magna nisl, mollis quis, molestie eu, feugiat in, orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.']

book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ws1', startrow=0, index=False)
writer.save()
```

test.xlsx looks like:

[image]

and my code inserts df:

[image]

but my desired result is:

[image]

I've formatted the excel sheet column but it gets lost when df is written to the worksheet. I can wrap text with Alignment(wrap_text=True) if I'm creating a new worksheet but not sure how to apply it to the column of an existing worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1,2]
df['reviews'] = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Curabitur pretium tincidunt lacus. Nulla gravida orci a odio. Nullam varius, turpis et commodo pharetra, est eros bibendum elit, nec luctus magna felis sollicitudin mauris. Integer in mauris eu nibh euismod gravida. Duis ac tellus et risus vulputate vehicula. Donec lobortis risus a elit. Etiam tempor. Ut ullamcorper, ligula eu tempor congue, eros est euismod turpis, id tincidunt sapien risus a quam. Maecenas fermentum consequat mi. Donec fermentum. Pellentesque', 'malesuada nulla a mi. Duis sapien sem, aliquet nec, commodo eget, consequat quis, neque. Aliquam faucibus, elit ut dictum aliquet, felis nisl adipiscing sapien, sed malesuada diam lacus eget erat. Cras mollis scelerisque nunc. Nullam arcu. Aliquam consequat. Curabitur augue lorem, dapibus quis, laoreet et, pretium ac, nisi. Aenean magna nisl, mollis quis, molestie eu, feugiat in, orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.']

book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}

# writer.sheets['ws1'].column_dimensions['B'].width = 90  # you can also adjust the column width if need be

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ws1', startrow=0, index=False)

for cell in writer.sheets['ws1']['B']:
    cell.alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)

writer.save()
```

Comment: my actual data is larger than the sample I created. When I apply it to the larger dataset the code only wraps the first 2 rows of col B. I'm not sure why Alignment(wrap_text=True) isn't applied to every row of the column.

Comment: I have changed the position of the cell alignment command in the code - could you try again?

Comment: changing the cell alignment in the code worked. I would have never thought that format-write would behave differently from write-format. Thanks again.